# Can I change the ipconfig names to the old convention? wlanX, ethX?

Tags: bash, alias, ifconfig

Some time ago there was a monumental change in the naming convention for networking in Ubuntu. wlanx became some strange vlp43txuv and eth0 became enpcl231.

Why it became to be an ordinary user like me can only imagine. It is not a good vision.

1 Is it possible to either change this globally on the system through alias, of sorts or

2 Is it possible to change it temporarily every time I run bash or some script?

It would make my life a lot easier to use the old naming convention as it is the quickest way to use. Now I have to check it every time because I cannot remember the new names at all.

If there are any hidden risks involved, please write those too. Perhaps a locked variable cannot work properly if an alias is changed and so forth.

---

EDIT:
I came across this video on the different naming conventions that have been used. Here I found that the strange names comes from the PCI location

[Netdev 2.1 What's in a name](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1SUnpH5Mt4s)

I forgot. The solution to my problem was just changing a line in grub as suggested in the duplicate thread. I did not have to change /etc/...

Comment: Viewing the link by Arronical, there seems to be a solution but are you really sure you want to start fiddling with something crucial like network settings? There is always the risk you lose connectivity. I get the impression you rely the old naming. As you are already willing to run some script, perhaps you could bite the bullet and change your dependencies on the old naming?

Comment: I prefer a good old solution to a new worse solution. I cannot see what was gained with the new names only a loss in ease of use. If the solution in the possible duplicate does not work I will have to reinstall my system again after the crash. Thanks, guys.

Comment: @Arronical That was perhaps a duplicate, but the answers did not work. There is no /etc/udev/rules.d/70...... on the system. I conclude a new question is in place for a new situation.

Comment: I believe that in the link given by Arronical, the answer by Syed is correct. It has `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="net.ifnames=0"`, and that's what I have in mine and it does as you request. The "new" names were supposed to make it easier for systems with multiple "slots" and "ports", so a name like "en0s1p0" means ethernet 0, slot 1, port 0.

Comment: @DrillBit  if you don't have that file on the system, create it.  Here's my example: `SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC Address Here>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan1"`

Comment: @heynnema and Sergeiy. Thanks guys, I will try those suggestions. As I wrote, we mere mortals do not have such complicated systems yet.

Comment: @DrillBit I have to take a step back... I looked at my `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` and I see that I've defined "proper" device names for all of my network devices... so now I can't remember... which one "fixed" the problem for me... the `net.ifnames=0` or the file... or both.